# How big before a member function typically not inlined?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, inline

How large do member functions need to be before the compiler decides against inlining them?

(Assume GCC and o2/o3 or any other high optimization switches).

Comment: Why guess? Look at the assembler output for your particular function and see if it was inlined or not.

Comment: It depends on how you use the function. I once investigated a case when the compiler amalgamated a number of medium-sized functions into a monster sized in tens of kilobytes. The functions were declared `static` and therefore the compiler could detect that each of them is called exactly once.

Comment: This depends in part on the compiler and it's version (default threshholds have been changed at various times), the content of the function (there are some constructs that make even a very small function difficult to inline) and other things like `static`, etc. It may also depend on platform and instruction set details, as well as arguments called (in some cases a specific argument may make parts of the function provably dead). In other words, I don't think there is a single simple answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom but I do not want a "yes" or "no" answer- I want a "X bytes" answer.

Comment: @user997112: 42 bytes. Precisely.

Comment: Do you mind reviewing the answers to see if some fits you and accept, or explain why not?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the larger a function becomes, the smaller the benefit of inlining.

One of the main purposes for inlining is to avoid the function call and return overhead.

Small functions, such as getters and setters, are prime candidates.

Larger functions are usually not inlined.  This due to the ratio of data processing instructions to the size of the call and return overhead.  The overhead is small compared to the content in the function.  In general, removing the function call and return overhead will have a negligible impact on the program's performance.

As for the size threshold, it is compiler dependent.  For GCC, you should look up the documentation or look at the decision point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The default threshold size for gcc inline is 600.  You can change that with the flag `-finline-limit`

Notice that the measure of *function size* is not directly made in bytes nor instruction count, but other measurement applied by the compiler, which makes pretty hard to determine whether a function will or not be inlined. You can *assume* based on functions inlined to certain value of `-finline-limit` the inlineability of other sized functions to other values of the flag.

Then again, size alone doesn't guarantee inline, though, and decision may vary with other flags/ compiler version.

There is a good reason for this mess: since inlining is mostly due to performance, the compiler adjusts it's measures to target architecture/function usage.

---

Source:

[GCC Optimization Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)